# How to run a cron job using launchd?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, script, launchd

I have a simple `cron` job:

```
MAILTO=“”
0 9 * * * /path/to/job
```

My issue with this job being that it won’t run if my Mac isn’t up and running (sleep mode). I read `launchd/launchctl` may be what I’m looking for. The manual is long and intimidating and the specifications seem complex. What is the simplest way to transform this `cron` job into something that’ll run even when my Mac is off?

MacOS Ventura 13.3.1

Comment: Run when it's powered off?  There is nothing.

Comment: @MarcWilson when it is sleeping